# Reuse TokenCredential when connecting to Azure Storage using Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a Web API application that connects to Azure Storage Blobs using Azure AD.

This are the libraries used:

This is the code that creates a BlobServiceClient. This is executed for each request that needs to access the storage account blobs. Do I need

```
    var blobClientOptions = new BlobClientOptions();
    blobClientOptions.Diagnostics.IsLoggingEnabled = true;
    blobClientOptions.Diagnostics.IsTelemetryEnabled = true;
    blobClientOptions.Diagnostics.IsDistributedTracingEnabled = false;

    blobClientOptions.Retry.Mode = RetryMode.Exponential;
    blobClientOptions.Retry.MaxRetries = 5;

    var storageAccountUrl = $"https://{_storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net";
    _blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri(storageAccountUrl), new DefaultAzureCredential(), blobClientOptions);
```

Should I cache and reuse the TokenCredential; does it has an expiration time?
What are the best practices when connecting to Azure Storage Accounts using Azure AD?

Answer (score 0):

The credential itself does not cache tokens.
In the new Azure SDKs, the HTTP pipeline that the BlobServiceClient (and other API clients) uses caches tokens and requests new tokens from the credential when needed.
You can use a new credential or cache it, either way works.
We have used a singleton credential object.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but it seems relevant to point to Microsoft page since they no longer support token refresh ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/whats-new#refresh-and-session-token-lifetimes-configurability-in-configurable-token-lifetime-ctl-are-retired))

> Refresh and session token lifetimes configurability in Configurable
> Token Lifetime (CTL) are retired Type: Deprecated Service category:
> Other Product capability: User Authentication
>
> Refresh and session token lifetimes configurability in CTL are
> retired. Azure Active Directory no longer honors refresh and session
> token configuration in existing policies. Learn more.